# Customizing EditTextPreference

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I would like to customize my *EditTextPreference*. My goal is formatting the title text. Here is a relevant part of my *prefs.xml*

```
<com.widgets.FormattedEditTextPreference
    android:dialogTitle="android password"
    android:summary="password to this app"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:key="sLoginPassw"
    android:title="android password" />
```

Here is the code behind:

```
public class FormattedEditTextPreference extends EditTextPreference {
public FormattedEditTextPreference( Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle ) {
    super( context, attrs, defStyle );
    setDialogTitle( context.getResources().getString( R.string.app_name )+attrs.getAttributeValue( 0 ) );
}

public FormattedEditTextPreference( Context context, AttributeSet attrs ) {
    super( context, attrs );
    setDialogTitle( context.getResources().getString( R.string.app_name )+attrs.getAttributeValue( 0 ) );
}

public FormattedEditTextPreference( Context context ) {
    super( context );
    setDialogTitle( context.getResources().getString( R.string.app_name ) );
}
}
```

This code isn't elegant enough but works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Donot override setDialogTitle, call setDialogTitle("") in each of the constructor. It is used by apps but not by the Preference component.

Comment: My goal is formatting or extending the text comes from static xml. Your solution would be clear it instead of. What do you meaan "It is used by apps but not by the Preference component"?

Comment: In the constructor, EditTextPreference directly accesses the  android:dialogTitle attribute, and sets the internal title string, so overriding setDialogTitle will not help

Comment: _super( context, attrs ); 
setDialogTitle( context.getResources().getString( R.string.app_name )+attrs.getAttributeValue( 0 ) );_ 
didn't helped in the constructor

Comment: In all the constructors, not just in one

Comment: didn't helped too, because the middle constructor(ctx,attrs) is called only.